# Array (list?) required, but int found error

Tags: java, arrays

I have the following code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class TestCandidate2
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
 ArrayList<Candidate> election = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

 Candidate john = new Candidate("John Smith", 5000);
 election.add(john);
 Candidate mary = new Candidate("Mary Miller", 4000);
 election.add(mary);
 Candidate michael = new Candidate("Micheal Duffy", 6000);
 election.add(michael);
 Candidate tim = new Candidate("Tim Robinson", 2500);
 election.add(tim);
 Candidate joe = new Candidate("Joe Ashtony", 1800);
 election.add(joe);

 System.out.println("Results Per Candidate:");
 System.out.println("________________________");
 System.out.print("\n");
 int totalVotes = 0;
 int total = 0;

 for(Candidate dec : election) {
    System.out.println(dec.toString());
    total += dec.getVotes();
    totalVotes += dec.getVotes();
 }

 System.out.print("\n");
 System.out.println("Total number of votes in election: " + totalVotes);
}

public static void printVotes(ArrayList<Candidate> table) {
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(table.size()[i]);
    }
}

/**public static int getTotal(ArrayList<Candidate> table)  {
    int total = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
       total = table[i].getVotes() + total;
    }
    return total;
}*/

/**public static void printResults(ArrayList<Candidate> table)  {
    double total = getTotal(table);
    System.out.print("Candidate               Votes Received              % of Total Votes");
    System.out.print("\n");
    for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
       System.out.printf("%s %17d %25.0f", table[i].getName(), table[i].getVotes(), ((table[i].getVotes() / total) * 100));
       System.out.println("");
    }
}*/
}
```

Now first off the error I think I should be getting is 'arraylist required, but int found', but instead the error that I am getting is 'array required, but int found'.

I do not know how I should fix the int i, for whenever I put [] to declare it as an array I still get errors. I have tried researching, but no one seems to have my exact problem.

Comment: Which line of code is causing the error?

Comment: System.out.println(table.size()[i]);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You appear to be accessing your `List`s incorrectly. Instead of:

```
table[i].getVotes()
```

try:

```
table.get(i).getVotes();
```

Or avoid using indexes altogether. For example, you could rewrite `getTotal()` as:

```
public static int getTotal(List<Candidate> candidates) {
    int total = 0;
    foreach (Candidate c : candidates) {
        total += c.getVotes();
    }
    return total;
}
```

The line producing the error:

```
System.out.println(table.size()[i]);
```

is a little confusing, but I think you want:

```
System.out.println(table.get(i).getVotes());
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked for me and I now understand why it didn't before.

Comment: No problem. If you're happy with an answer, you can accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`List.get(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get%28int%29) to get an element by position (not `[]` that's for arrays). Also, I suggest you program to the list interface. Like

```
public static void printVotes(List<Candidate> table) {
    for(int i = 0; i < table.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(table.get(i));
    }
}
```

You could also use a [`for-each` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/85190/how-does-the-java-for-each-loop-work) and `+=` like,

```
public static int getTotal(List<Candidate> table)  {
    int total = 0;
    for(Candidate c : table) {
       total += c.getVotes();
    }
    return total;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use `table.get(i)` instead of `table[i]`. this is an `ArrayList` not an array